# Why is KeyValueConfigurationCollection not sealed?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

[KeyValueConfigurationCollection is not sealed](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a8dce7c1c905e994c9519e0f26b0497832942a10/src/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/KeyValueConfigurationCollection.cs#L8).

All other configuration collections are sealed for both `netframework` and `corefx`:
 [NameValueConfigurationCollection](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a8dce7c1c905e994c9519e0f26b0497832942a10/src/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/NameValueConfigurationCollection.cs#L8), [ConnectionStringSettingsCollection](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a8dce7c1c905e994c9519e0f26b0497832942a10/src/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.cs#L8), [ProviderSettingsCollection](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a8dce7c1c905e994c9519e0f26b0497832942a10/src/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/ProviderSettingsCollection.cs#L8), [SchemeSettingElementCollection](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a8dce7c1c905e994c9519e0f26b0497832942a10/src/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/SchemeSettingElementCollection.cs#L12).

There are some subclasses of `KeyValueConfigurationCollection` in `corefx` repository, but only for test purposes.

Is `KeyValueConfigurationCollection` not sealed only for tests or there are other design reasons for that?

Comment: If there is anything that derives from it, it can't be sealed.  It seems like you'e answered your own question.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I write tests for `System.Configuration` as a contibution for `corefx`. Do you think I should propose API changes if tests will benefit from that?

Comment: If there's no other way to do those tests, I think that's a reasonable benefit.  But, it does open up integration possibilities that did not exist before and thus new support possibilities. So, the pros and cons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class is unsealed so others can inherit from it.  So presumably it was left unsealed because it was thought that people would want to subclass it.  The fact that it **is** subclassed for test cases, indicates that it was the right thing to do.  If subclassing it can help with testing it (or something else) then there are probably other scenarios where it is beneficial.